# How to access Google ajax data using Java/Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver/Java. And I have given input "iphone" in google search box.

But I want to select "iphone 6" from the list shown by google search. How can I do that using Java/Selenium Webdriver?

[Please refer to this link for further understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLq66.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to select the exact "iphone 6" string? Or you want to select the first line in the proposed search options? Please elaborate.

Comment: try to use an browser addon, which shows you the page source, like firebug: https://getfirebug.com/firstrun#Firebug%202.0.9 , then look at the page source and use a good locator. you can search for className= "sbsb_b" to get the list box and search this for li tags to get every line.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[role='option']"));
for (WebElement w: options)
    if (w.getText().equals("iphone 6")){
        w.click();
        break;
    }
```